# When creating a Win2012 cluster "The network name is already used on the network" no matter what name is used

Tags: cluster, windows-server-2012

I have a test setup that has 2 Windows Server 2012 VMs on Hyper-V joined to a windows 2008 R2 domain - there is an internal network whose DNS server is on the domain controller and an external network whose DNS server is also a Windows 2008 R2 box.

All Cluster validation tests pass.

When I get to the first screen in the Create Cluster Wizard which asks for the Cluster Name, no matter what I type in the box, I get the error "The network name {0} is already used in the network" - the error comes back almost immediately and there are no events in the System or Application logs of any of the servers.

I have Windows 2008 R2 VMs with clusters on this exact setup.  I'm happy to post more information, but I don't even know where to start looking at this point.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a default DNS record configured on your internal DNS?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - possibly not - I followed some directions I found (a while ago) to configure the DNS server and it worked with my Win 2008 R2 clusters - haven't touched it since - I'm a SQL guy - not much of a network guy...

Comment: It's probably fine, try running `ping aklasjdlfjskd` on the command line. It should return "host not found" or similar. If it finds an IP to ping, you've got a default record somewhere that's tripping up the cluster.

Comment: It returns with the IP address of a server at opendns which is where the external DNS server goes when looking up external addresses - All that is set up on the external DNS server is a forwarder - I need that (I think) in order to resolve external addresses - not sure how to make it work properly, but at least I know where to start looking now - thanks

Comment: Excellent - I added a Forward lookup zone on my external DNS server for my domain - this presumably became authoritative on the domain and it stopped forwarding the requests to OpenDNS - do you want to propose an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily disable your external network adapter and ping aklasjdlfjskd. This time the ping should return "Host not found" or a similar error. Repeat the step to add a cluster name and ip address and it should work fine. After this you can re-enable your external network adapter.

Comment: Just for the sake of random curiosity, what is this supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the answer already given (but in comment):

A wildcard (`*`) record exists in DNS, making the checks come back positive. Delete this A/AAAA/CNAME record.

> Sidenote: It seems that this process performs its checks through DNS rather than over an API, even if it were a DNS check — vs checking for a machine account or alias in AD — but through an API, there would be no false positives.